# Django/PostgreSQL custom TimeRangeField

Tags: django, postgresql

I'm trying to create a `TimeRangeField` but am having some problems saving to the database (PostgreSQL version 9.5.23).

```
from psycopg2.extras import DateTimeRange

from django import forms
from django.contrib.postgres.forms import BaseRangeField
from django.contrib.postgres.fields.ranges import RangeField
from django.db import models


class TimeRangeFormField(BaseRangeField):
    default_error_messages = {'invalid': 'Enter two valid times.'}
    base_field = forms.TimeField
    range_type = DateTimeRange


class TimeRangeField(RangeField):
    base_field = models.TimeField
    range_type = DateTimeRange
    form_field = TimeRangeFormField

    def db_type(self, connection):
        return 'tsrange'
```

The error when saving seems pretty self explanatory - pretty sure I need to cast the time object to a string but I have no idea how to do that.

```
function tsrange(time without time zone, time without time zone, unknown) does not exist
LINE 1: ...('b9925dd3-d4a8-4914-8e85-7380d9a33de5'::uuid, 1, tsrange('1...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Here's the SQL:

```
INSERT INTO "fulfillment_deliveryslot"
        (
                    "uuid",
                    "day_id",
                    "window",
                    "max_orders",
                    "is_active"
        )
        VALUES
        (
                    'b9925dd3-d4a8-4914-8e85-7380d9a33de5'::uuid,
                    1,
                    tsrange('12:38:31'::time, '13:00:00'::time, '[)'),
                    5,
                    true
        )
        returning "fulfillment_deliveryslot"."id"
```

Comment: what postgres version do you run

Comment: @iklinac V 9.5.23

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is here: `time without time zone`. You are using `tsrange` and that needs a timestamp:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/rangetypes.html

> tsrange — Range of timestamp without time zone

In other words you are passing a time into something that needs a timestamp.

Comment: Ah, can't believe I missed that - thanks. So it seems like it's unnecessary to use a custom field as I can just use `DateRangeField`

Comment: Yes, if all you care about is a date range. Since you seen to be concerned with times I would think that `DateTimeRangeField` would be more appropriate.